# Something similar to inotifywait, without being able to install inotifywait

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I wanted to continuously re-build and test projects, but just discovered my school's RHEL distribution doesn't come with inotify or inotifywait.

Are there any alternatives I could use, which would not require the use of sudo?

I just want to automatically re-`make` when files change.

EDIT: I'm using polling instead (which is funny, because I'm doing this for a class on concurrency), so anything better than this would be useful

```
watch:  
    while true; do \
        make | grep -v -e "Nothing to" -e "Entering" -e "Leaving"; \
        sleep 1; \
    done
```

Comment: im not pretty sure about this but you are in the edge to be offtopic with software recomendation.

Comment: I see what you're saying, though I feel that this is more about just solving a problem in linux and it just happens to be that it's related to a particular piece of software. The problem is 'how to inotifywait without inotifywait'

Comment: that's why i dont flag, but be carefull to be in the edge, some ppl just flag, without read carefully.

Comment: I added the relevant part of my makefile to make the question more relevant. Thanks

Comment: The inotify api is in the kernel since 2.6.13. That's quite old. Are you sure your kernel was compiled without CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y. The api is fairly simple to use from C, or you could install the inotify-tools src rpm and compile it.

Comment: School computer, I don't have root access

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is [fschange](http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/fschange/). You can download the source code from the above link and compile it yourself.

There is also [dir_minotor](http://www.highscore.de/boost/dir_monitor.zip) (see for instance [this Web page](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html) for further info), a cross-platform solution in C++. I have never used it, just stored the link for `possible  ' future use.

As for `inotify`, I do not use RHEL so I am out of my depth here, but are you sure you should find it in the repos? It is implemented in the kernel, not as a repo package. You may try installing [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) and see whether your kernel does indeed have support for `inotify`. You can do this **even** if you do not have access to `sudo`:

Download the source code locally (*i.e.* on `/home/your_name`), compile it, install it in `/home/your_name/bin`, run it on your own files locally. This is what I used to do when I was a lowly undergrad, I have not tried it with inotify-tools but it should be absolutely doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [systemd path unit](https://support.pingcap.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410110056471-Monitor-changes-to-paths-and-files-using-systemd) to monitor a file or a directory. A [systemd user instance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User) won't require root access, and it should be enabled by default on RHEL. Use `systemctl --user` to issue commands and `/usr/lib/systemd/user/` to add your units, e.g., `projectrebuild.path` and `projectrebuild.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description="Monitor my project files and rebuild if changes occur"

[Path]
PathModified=/some/path/to/monitor
Unit=projectrebuild.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description="Rebuild project"

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/build/script
```

```
systemctl --user enable --now projectrebuild.path
```